# Forked library doesn't create dist folder in node-modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, node-modules

I have a problem with vue js plugin. It's this: https://github.com/antoniandre/vue-cal

I forked it and changed that I wanted, but when I want to install the node_modules folder is created without the dist folder. What can be the problem?

The package.json is the same as the author's.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by "install the node_modules folder" How did you build the package? How did you publish it?

Comment: I installed the wanted branch from github with npm git://github... It created the Vue-cal folder in node_modules but without the dist folder

Comment: A sourcecode repository like github typically does not contain the dist folder. If you want your package to contain also the compiled package, you will have to add it to the respository.